# Eslint not recognizing Reflect

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, reflect

I'm using Reflect in my code. Problem is Eslint thinks its an undeclared variable. I'm getting this error:

```
eslint --config ./.eslintrc.json src

30:25  error  'Reflect' is not defined  no-undef
32:9   error  'Reflect' is not defined  no-undef
39:21  error  'Reflect' is not defined  no-undef
40:5   error  'Reflect' is not defined  no-undef
```

I have my `.eslintrc` file set to ECMAScript 2015:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2015,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "globalReturn": true
    }
  }
```

Not sure why it's applying the `no-undef` rule to Reflect. All my code is typically ECMAScript 2015, nothing unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to setting the `ecmaVersion`, you need to tell it to include "es6" globals:

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

(You'll probably want others in there too, such as `browser`.)

More in [Specifying Environments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) in the docs.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. I was not expecting having to set es6 in two places: parserOptions and env. In fact, just removed "ecmaVersion": 2015 from parserOptions and left es6 in env. and it works. So I'm wondering why you would ever need the parserOptions setting.

Comment: @RobertBiggs - If you use the `es6` `env` setting, it sets `ecmaVersion` to `6` (`2015`). If you want to use later features (like property spread from ES2018), you'd want to set `ecmaVersion` to something higher. I think they're separated because some people transpile advanced syntax but don't use polyfills for new builtins.